dyld_process_snapshot_get_shared_cache failed on startup | flutter ios
After finish building an iOS app in Flutter, the app crashes when I try to launch it in an emulator.
The logs showed dyld_process_snapshot_get_shared_cache, but I have no idea what this is.
I tried flutter clean and regenerating Podfile, but nothing worked.
flutter doctor -v
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.24.2, on macOS 14.6.1 23G93 darwin-arm64, locale ja-JP)
    • Flutter version 3.24.2 on channel stable at /Users/yukikomine/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 4cf269e36d (6 days ago), 2024-09-03 14:30:00 -0700
    • Engine revision a6bd3f1de1
    • Dart version 3.5.2
    • DevTools version 2.37.2

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 32.1.0-rc1)
    • Android SDK at /Users/yukikomine/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-33, build-tools 32.1.0-rc1
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.12+0-b1504.28-7817840)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 15.4)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Build 15F31d
    • CocoaPods version 1.15.2

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.2)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.12+0-b1504.28-7817840)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.93.0)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.96.0

[✓] Connected device (4 available)
    • iPhone 15 Pro Max (mobile)      • D7CC5526-943C-4B9A-8185-23AD4F793600 • ios            • com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-17-5 (simulator)
    • macOS (desktop)                 • macos                                • darwin-arm64   • macOS 14.6.1 23G93 darwin-arm64
    • Mac Designed for iPad (desktop) • mac-designed-for-ipad                • darwin         • macOS 14.6.1 23G93 darwin-arm64
    • Chrome (web)                    • chrome                               • web-javascript • Google Chrome 128.0.6613.120

[✓] Network resources
    • All expected network resources are available.

• No issues found!

crash report
-------------------------------------
Translated Report (Full Report Below)
-------------------------------------

Incident Identifier: D4A133A4-D342-4EA0-993D-21E64258E1F7
CrashReporter Key:   F97C6360-09E3-2B46-752A-09B8F1A1746B
Hardware Model:      MacBookPro17,1
Process:             Runner [78925]
Path:                /Users/USER/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/D7CC5526-943C-4B9A-8185-23AD4F793600/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/429C61FA-4E69-45B2-BC66-10350D72475C/Runner.app/Runner
Identifier:          com.example.example
Version:             1.0.1 (2)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd_sim [3284]
Coalition:           com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.D7CC5526-943C-4B9A-8185-23AD4F793600 [1704]
Responsible Process: SimulatorTrampoline [1977]

Date/Time:           2024-09-10 17:05:27.0619 +0900
Launch Time:         2024-09-10 17:05:24.8704 +0900
OS Version:          macOS 14.6.1 (23G93)
Release Type:        User
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Termination Reason: SIGNAL 6 Abort trap: 6
Terminating Process: Runner [78925]

Triggered by Thread:  0

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                         0x10f0810ec __exceptionPreprocess + 160
1   libobjc.A.dylib                        0x108bdfdb4 objc_exception_throw + 56
2   CoreFoundation                         0x10f081008 -[NSException initWithCoder:] + 0
3   Runner                                 0x104d4ed78 +[GMSServices checkServicePreconditions] + 260
4   Runner                                 0x104d4cb38 +[GMSServices preLaunchServices] + 112
5   Runner                                 0x1054fe7d0 -[FLTGoogleMapFactory sharedMapServices] + 60
6   Runner                                 0x1054fe700 -[FLTGoogleMapFactory createWithFrame:viewIdentifier:arguments:] + 84
7   Flutter                                0x11a601444 flutter::FlutterPlatformViewsController::OnCreate(FlutterMethodCall*, void (objc_object*) block_pointer) + 836 (FlutterPlatformViews.mm:229)
8   Flutter                                0x11a600f9c flutter::FlutterPlatformViewsController::OnMethodCall(FlutterMethodCall*, void (objc_object*) block_pointer) + 140 (FlutterPlatformViews.mm:178)
9   Flutter                                0x11abf4474 __45-[FlutterMethodChannel setMethodCallHandler:]_block_invoke + 164 (FlutterChannels.mm:322)
10  Flutter                                0x11a62ee4c fml::RefPtr<flutter::PlatformMessageResponse>::~RefPtr() + 0 (ref_ptr.h:110) [inlined]
11  Flutter                                0x11a62ee4c fml::RefPtr<flutter::PlatformMessageResponse>::~RefPtr() + 0 (ref_ptr.h:109) [inlined]
12  Flutter                                0x11a62ee4c invocation function for block in flutter::PlatformMessageHandlerIos::HandlePlatformMessage(std::_fl::unique_ptr<flutter::PlatformMessage, std::_fl::default_delete<flutter::PlatformMessage>>) + 108 (platform_message_handler_ios.mm:81)
13  libdispatch.dylib                      0x10b10a104 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
14  libdispatch.dylib                      0x10b10b978 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
15  libdispatch.dylib                      0x10b11a7c8 _dispatch_main_queue_drain + 1276
16  libdispatch.dylib                      0x10b11a2bc _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 40
17  CoreFoundation                         0x10efe1960 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 12
18  CoreFoundation                         0x10efdc078 __CFRunLoopRun + 1936
19  CoreFoundation                         0x10efdb4d4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 572
20  GraphicsServices                       0x12203bae4 GSEventRunModal + 160
21  UIKitCore                              0x13ea71a28 -[UIApplication _run] + 868
22  UIKitCore                              0x13ea756b0 UIApplicationMain + 124
23  UIKitCore                              0x13df146a8 0x13de80000 + 607912
24  Runner                                 0x104d2348c static UIApplicationDelegate.main() + 120
25  Runner                                 0x104d23404 static AppDelegate.$main() + 44
26  Runner                                 0x104d23508 main + 28 (AppDelegate.swift:5)
27  dyld_sim                               0x106905544 start_sim + 20
28  dyld                                   0x10641a154 start + 2476
29  ???                             0x5a2b800000000000 ???

Thread 0 Crashed::  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x10ea00f30 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x10eb5b124 pthread_kill + 256
2   libsystem_c.dylib                      0x10b0475c0 abort + 104
3   libc++abi.dylib                        0x109e57778 abort_message + 128
4   libc++abi.dylib                        0x109e48ecc demangling_terminate_handler() + 300
5   libobjc.A.dylib                        0x108bbb498 _objc_terminate() + 124
6   libc++abi.dylib                        0x109e56c50 std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 12
7   libc++abi.dylib                        0x109e56c00 std::terminate() + 52
8   libdispatch.dylib                      0x10b10b98c _dispatch_client_callout + 36
9   libdispatch.dylib                      0x10b11a7c8 _dispatch_main_queue_drain + 1276
10  libdispatch.dylib                      0x10b11a2bc _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 40
11  CoreFoundation                         0x10efe1960 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 12
12  CoreFoundation                         0x10efdc078 __CFRunLoopRun + 1936
13  CoreFoundation                         0x10efdb4d4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 572
14  GraphicsServices                       0x12203bae4 GSEventRunModal + 160
15  UIKitCore                              0x13ea71a28 -[UIApplication _run] + 868
16  UIKitCore                              0x13ea756b0 UIApplicationMain + 124
17  UIKitCore                              0x13df146a8 0x13de80000 + 607912
18  Runner                                 0x104d2348c static UIApplicationDelegate.main() + 120
19  Runner                                 0x104d23404 static AppDelegate.$main() + 44
20  Runner                                 0x104d23508 main + 28 (AppDelegate.swift:5)
21  dyld_sim                               0x106905544 start_sim + 20
22  dyld                                   0x10641a154 start + 2476

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x10eb565cc start_wqthread + 0

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x10eb565cc start_wqthread + 0

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x10eb565cc start_wqthread + 0

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x10eb565cc start_wqthread + 0

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x10eb565cc start_wqthread + 0

Thread 6:: com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x10e9f9170 mach_msg2_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x10ea0a660 mach_msg2_internal + 76
2   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x10ea01318 mach_msg_overwrite + 532
3   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x10e9f94e8 mach_msg + 20
4   CoreFoundation                         0x10efe1684 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 156
5   CoreFoundation                         0x10efdbd64 __CFRunLoopRun + 1148
6   CoreFoundation                         0x10efdb4d4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 572
7   Foundation                             0x11231f40c -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 208
8   Foundation                             0x11231f630 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] + 60
9   UIKitCore                              0x13eb183f8 -[UIEventFetcher threadMain] + 404
10  Foundation                             0x112345c64 __NSThread__start__ + 720
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x10eb5b414 _pthread_start + 104
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x10eb565e0 thread_start + 8

Error Formulating Crash Report:
dyld_process_snapshot_get_shared_cache failed

EOF

-----------
Full Report
-----------

{"app_name":"Runner","timestamp":"2024-09-10 17:05:33.00 +0900","app_version":"1.0.1","slice_uuid":"bce83ed0-d707-3fa3-a53e-0e4cc947a9c3","build_version":"2","platform":7,"bundleID":"com.example.example","share_with_app_devs":0,"is_first_party":0,"bug_type":"309","os_version":"macOS 14.6.1 (23G93)","roots_installed":0,"name":"Runner","incident_id":"D4A133A4-D342-4EA0-993D-21E64258E1F7"}
{
  "uptime" : 3800,
  "procRole" : "Foreground",
  "version" : 2,
  "userID" : 501,
  "deployVersion" : 210,
  "modelCode" : "MacBookPro17,1",
  "coalitionID" : 1704,
  "osVersion" : {
    "train" : "macOS 14.6.1",
    "build" : "23G93",
    "releaseType" : "User"
  },
  "captureTime" : "2024-09-10 17:05:27.0619 +0900",
  "codeSigningMonitor" : 1,
  "incident" : "D4A133A4-D342-4EA0-993D-21E64258E1F7",
  "pid" : 78925,
  "translated" : false,
  "cpuType" : "ARM-64",
  "roots_installed" : 0,
  "bug_type" : "309",
  "procLaunch" : "2024-09-10 17:05:24.8704 +0900",
  "procStartAbsTime" : 93226002127,
  "procExitAbsTime" : 93277888993,
  "procName" : "Runner",
  "procPath" : "\/Users\/USER\/Library\/Developer\/CoreSimulator\/Devices\/D7CC5526-943C-4B9A-8185-23AD4F793600\/data\/Containers\/Bundle\/Application\/429C61FA-4E69-45B2-BC66-10350D72475C\/Runner.app\/Runner",
  "bundleInfo" : {"CFBundleShortVersionString":"1.0.1","CFBundleVersion":"2","CFBundleIdentifier":"com.example.example"},
  "storeInfo" : {"deviceIdentifierForVendor":"85572FB4-AD18-5346-8498-1CA7C3B15305","thirdParty":true},
  "parentProc" : "launchd_sim",
  "parentPid" : 3284,
  "coalitionName" : "com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.D7CC5526-943C-4B9A-8185-23AD4F793600",
  "crashReporterKey" : "F97C6360-09E3-2B46-752A-09B8F1A1746B",
  "responsiblePid" : 1977,
  "responsibleProc" : "SimulatorTrampoline",
  "codeSigningID" : "com.example.example",
  "codeSigningTeamID" : "",
  "codeSigningFlags" : 570425861,
  "codeSigningValidationCategory" : 10,
  "codeSigningTrustLevel" : 4294967295,
  "instructionByteStream" : {"beforePC":"4wAAVP17v6n9AwCR9+L\/l78DAJH9e8GowANf1sADX9YQKYDSARAA1A==","atPC":"4wAAVP17v6n9AwCR7eL\/l78DAJH9e8GowANf1sADX9ZwCoDSARAA1A=="},
  "sip" : "enabled",
  "exception" : {"codes":"0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000","rawCodes":[0,0],"type":"EXC_CRASH","signal":"SIGABRT"},
  "termination" : {"flags":0,"code":6,"namespace":"SIGNAL","indicator":"Abort trap: 6","byProc":"Runner","byPid":78925},
  "extMods" : {"caller":{"thread_create":0,"thread_set_state":0,"task_for_pid":0},"system":{"thread_create":0,"thread_set_state":0,"task_for_pid":0},"targeted":{"thread_create":0,"thread_set_state":0,"task_for_pid":0},"warnings":0},
  "lastExceptionBacktrace" : [{"imageOffset":1233132,"symbol":"__exceptionPreprocess","symbolLocation":160,"imageIndex":49},

 ... omission

  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64",
    "base" : 5938249728,
    "CFBundleShortVersionString" : "1.0",
    "CFBundleIdentifier" : "com.apple.VideoSubscriberAccount.VideoSubscriberAccountFramework",
    "size" : 737280,
    "uuid" : "bc4930dc-f6a5-3c68-a716-7e59877d8222",
    "path" : "\/Volumes\/VOLUME\/*\/VideoSubscriberAccount.framework\/VideoSubscriberAccount",
    "name" : "VideoSubscriberAccount",
    "CFBundleVersion" : "511.50.13"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64",
    "base" : 5927600128,
    "CFBundleShortVersionString" : "2.8.10",
    "CFBundleIdentifier" : "com.apple.amp-ae-eng.MetricsKit",
    "size" : 393216,
    "uuid" : "ac979b24-f94d-3026-8767-6695f9e5ad74",
    "path" : "\/Volumes\/VOLUME\/*\/MetricsKit.framework\/MetricsKit",
    "name" : "MetricsKit",
    "CFBundleVersion" : "1"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64",
    "base" : 5936398336,
    "CFBundleShortVersionString" : "1.0",
    "CFBundleIdentifier" : "com.apple.MediaPlatform",
    "size" : 327680,
    "uuid" : "8c9188c4-bb47-3300-ba60-f7956ced954a",
    "path" : "\/Volumes\/VOLUME\/*\/MediaPlatform.framework\/MediaPlatform",
    "name" : "MediaPlatform",
    "CFBundleVersion" : "4023.600.5"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64",
    "base" : 5951193088,
    "CFBundleShortVersionString" : "1.0",
    "CFBundleIdentifier" : "com.apple.MediaLibraryCore",
    "size" : 3473408,
    "uuid" : "338ddd98-4ff1-3509-b985-21c3759b1864",
    "path" : "\/Volumes\/VOLUME\/*\/MediaLibraryCore.framework\/MediaLibraryCore",
    "name" : "MediaLibraryCore",
    "CFBundleVersion" : "4023.600.2"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64",
    "base" : 5956730880,
    "CFBundleShortVersionString" : "1.0.0",
    "CFBundleIdentifier" : "com.apple.MusicLibrary",
    "size" : 2818048,
    "uuid" : "87de6edd-8e4e-3f3f-89b1-94940e298844",
    "path" : "\/Volumes\/VOLUME\/*\/MusicLibrary.framework\/MusicLibrary",
    "name" : "MusicLibrary",
    "CFBundleVersion" : "4023.610.4"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64",
    "base" : 5928583168,
    "CFBundleShortVersionString" : "1.0",
    "CFBundleIdentifier" : "com.apple.HomeSharing",
    "size" : 196608,
    "uuid" : "c36b6c5f-caaa-367f-af5e-848573e5e4bf",
    "path" : "\/Volumes\/VOLUME\/*\/HomeSharing.framework\/HomeSharing",
    "name" : "HomeSharing",
    "CFBundleVersion" : "4023.600.5"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64",
    "base" : 4375838720,
    "CFBundleShortVersionString" : "1.0.1",
    "CFBundleIdentifier" : "com.example.example",
    "size" : 11599872,
    "uuid" : "bce83ed0-d707-3fa3-a53e-0e4cc947a9c3",
    "path" : "\/Users\/USER\/Library\/Developer\/CoreSimulator\/Devices\/D7CC5526-943C-4B9A-8185-23AD4F793600\/data\/Containers\/Bundle\/Application\/429C61FA-4E69-45B2-BC66-10350D72475C\/Runner.app\/Runner",
    "name" : "Runner",
    "CFBundleVersion" : "2"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64",
    "base" : 4405084160,
    "size" : 311296,
    "uuid" : "f1d509a4-edf1-3668-b217-c6a2bd1fbef4",
    "path" : "\/Volumes\/VOLUME\/*\/dyld_sim",
    "name" : "dyld_sim"
  },
  {
    "size" : 0,
    "source" : "A",
    "base" : 0,
    "uuid" : "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
  }
],
  "vmSummary" : "ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=1.4G resident=0K(0%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=1.4G(100%)\nWritable regions: Total=757.7M written=0K(0%) resident=0K(0%) swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=757.7M(100%)\n\n                                VIRTUAL   REGION \nREGION TYPE                        SIZE    COUNT (non-coalesced) \n===========                     =======  ======= \nActivity Tracing                   256K        1 \nColorSync                           64K        4 \nCoreAnimation                       16K        1 \nFoundation                          16K        1 \nIOSurface                         14.4M        2 \nKernel Alloc Once                   32K        1 \nMALLOC                           607.7M       51 \nMALLOC guard page                  192K       12 \nSTACK GUARD                       56.3M       21 \nStack                             27.1M       21 \nVM_ALLOCATE                      104.4M      291 \n__DATA                            32.0M      799 \n__DATA_CONST                      78.8M      707 \n__DATA_DIRTY                       176K       11 \n__FONT_DATA                         16K        1 \n__LINKEDIT                       601.6M      718 \n__TEXT                           795.8M      718 \ndyld private memory                6.0G       16 \nlibnetwork                         128K        8 \nmapped file                       89.6M       14 \nshared memory                       16K        1 \n===========                     =======  ======= \nTOTAL                              8.4G     3399 \n",
  "legacyInfo" : {
  "threadTriggered" : {
    "queue" : "com.apple.main-thread"
  }
},
  "logWritingSignature" : "1b3a913b9ba8c053184fe7c1b73c3fe59b0f55e0",
  "trialInfo" : {
  "rollouts" : [
    {
      "rolloutId" : "648c94d4ebdf9e3e398fa708",
      "factorPackIds" : {
        "SIRI_UNDERSTANDING_NL_OVERRIDES" : "65a8104b6712a43e7922cab8"
      },
      "deploymentId" : 240000171
    },
    {
      "rolloutId" : "648cada15dbc71671bb3aa1b",
      "factorPackIds" : {
        "SIRI_UNDERSTANDING_ATTENTION_ASSETS" : "65a8118e05d9422724106749",
        "SIRI_UNDERSTANDING_ASR_ASSISTANT" : "65a8115446dfa0720068876d",
        "SIRI_UNDERSTANDING_NL" : "65a811c046dfa0720068876e",
        "SIRI_EXPERIENCE_CAM" : "65a81173096f6a1f1ba46525",
        "SIRI_UNDERSTANDING_MORPHUN" : "65a811a96c2f903aa921c246"
      },
      "deploymentId" : 240000116
    }
  ],
  "experiments" : [
    {
      "treatmentId" : "5d85d104-adc7-4ebf-8b7c-96d84fdad9cc",
      "experimentId" : "6384d56b96e8d228551ec182",
      "deploymentId" : 400000032
    },
    {
      "treatmentId" : "ec94016c-752b-4f44-b6ea-d9ad1e3c8406",
      "experimentId" : "65c16ae095b5e23d93cdd97c",
      "deploymentId" : 400000006
    }
  ]
},
  "reportNotes" : [
  "dyld_process_snapshot_get_shared_cache failed"
]
}

Model: MacBookPro17,1, BootROM 10151.140.19, proc 8:4:4 processors, 8 GB, SMC 
Graphics: Apple M1, Apple M1, Built-In
Display: Color LCD, 2560 x 1600 Retina, Main, MirrorOff, Online
Memory Module: LPDDR4, Micron
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_wifi (0x14E4, 0x4378), wl0: Jan 13 2024 03:06:59 version 18.20.440.9.7.8.167 FWID 01-7be24857
AirPort: 
Bluetooth: Version (null), 0 services, 0 devices, 0 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en0
USB Device: USB31Bus
USB Device: USB31Bus
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc.
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc.



I've encountered the same issue but have no ideas how to fix

I was using google_maps_flutter plugin but I had not done any setup for iOS.
https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_flutter#ios
You need to comment out the widgets one by one to find out which plugin is causing the problem.

I was using google_maps_flutter plugin but I had not done any setup for iOS.
Crashes like this often seem to be caused by a specific plugin.
